# Angular 2 + Node Webkit

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, node-webkit

I'm new with Angular 2 and I want to know if I can use it with node webkit to create desktop aplications. Are they compatible? I know that Angular 2 creates a package.json same as nodewebkit, but they are different. So is there any chance to work with both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work because Angular 2 is a framework for browsers and NW is simply a chromium with nodejs. So you can turn every website into a NW standalone application.

You can put all dependencys in one package.json. Then in your main.js you open your index.html from Angular 2. To add more functionaly that are not avalible in browsers you can require modules in your angular app that are only avalible in node.js.

Maybe you should also take a look on electron, it is similar but runs 30% faster and i think easyer beacuse it is used more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :D